# iOS: Multiple prototype cells in one view produces skewed results

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, swift

In my storyboard I have 4 different prototype cells, each pertaining to a different "card" on a timeline view controller as demonstrated in the image below:

[image]

Appropriate constraints have been set, however when the timeline is loaded on the device the "cards" stack over each other as demonstrated in the image below:

[image]

I have been trying to get to the root of this problem for some time, but I really don't understand what is causing the layout to be so badly invalidated.

For reference, I am loading my cards in using the code below (I have stripped out un-necessary code which sets values of Outlets)

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var count = posts.count
    var cell: UITableViewCell!

    // Get the post we are currently on
    let p = posts[indexPath.row] as Post

    // Build the overview cell
    if indexPath.row == 0 {
        let userCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("UserCardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UserCardCell

        // outlet setting code here

        cell = userCell
    }
    // Handle other cell types
    else
    {
        if posts[indexPath.row].getType() == PostType.MEDIA
        {
            let mediaCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MediaCardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as MediaCardCell

            // outlet setting code here

            cell = mediaCell
        }

        if posts[indexPath.row].getType() == PostType.TEXT
        {
            let textCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("TextCardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as TextCardCell

            // outlet setting code here

            cell = textCell
        }

        if posts[indexPath.row].getType() == PostType.VERSUS
        {
            let versusCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("VersusCardCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as VersusCardCell

            // outlet setting code here

            cell = versusCell
        }
    }

    return cell
}
```

Any suggestions on what I may be doing wrong would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you setting the rowHeight property (or implementing heightForRowAtIndexPath)?

Comment: I am using `self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension` to set the heights dynamically

Comment: Are you also setting the estimatedRowHeight? Does the view correct itself after scrolling?

Comment: yes I am using estimated row height, setting it to 200 - but the problem still persists regardless

Comment: Just for a test, comment out those two lines and just set rowHeight to 200. See if that fixes the problem.

Comment: Very strange but taking out the estimated tow height and just using the auto size for row fixes it...I wonder why that is